# laravel using data in view that has been sent from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I always send data from view like this `->with(array('message'=>'there is an error '))`, and it works.

I want to allow the customer to edit some information, so when he/she clicks on the the edit like, this function in a controller is being executed:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $waitingTimes = WaitingTimes::find($id);
        return View::make('waitingtimes.edit')->with(array(
            'verticalMenu' => 'none',
            'verticalMenuTab' => 'none',
            'data' => $waitingTimes
        ));
    }
```

So later in the view, I should be able to say this:

```
$data->startTime, $data->endTime, $data->id, $data->restaurant_id
```

but every time I do that, I got `$data->startTime` printed on the browser, but I should have got the value of the `startTime` attribute.

This is my view:

```
<div class="oneInfo">
            {{ Form::text('startTime', '', array('class' => 'time ui-timepicker-input', 'id' => 'startTime', 'autocomplete' => 'off'))}}
            <span class="errorMessage">
                <?php
                echo $errors->first('startTime');
                ?>
            </span>
        </div>
```

The view has an input text and I want that input text to be filled with the data that has been sent from the controller.

how could I do that please?

Comment: From the looks of things, you could pull this off by using **[form model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding)**. There is a free **[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/lessons/form-model-binding)** that deals with the subject.

Comment: @Jeemusu that sounds interesting, let me try it

Comment: @Jeemusu and how to fill the inputs ? will they be filled automatically? in my case they are not

Comment: They should be filled automatically yes, I noticed on your code however you are setting the values to an empty string via the second parameter of the Form::text method.

Comment: @Jeemusu yes you right, when I did this `$data->startTime` in the second parameter, I got the data filled, many thanks type an answer to accept it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form::text()` method's second parameter allows you to pass it the value to be assigned to the input element. Your form input declarations are currently setting the value of the inputs to an empty string.

The best way to handle this would be to replace your empty string with `$value=null`.

```
{{ Form::text('startTime', $value=null, array('class' => 'time ui-timepicker-input', 'id' => 'startTime', 'autocomplete' => 'off'))}}
```

This will automatically replace the value with your models data or the data input by the user (should validation fail and you redirect back to the form).

From the looks of things, you could also make things a bit easier for yourself by using [form model binding](http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding) to bind the `WaitingTimes` model to your form.

Comment: Just one thing please, when I submit the form, I got `MethodNotAllowedHttpExcpetion` is that related to the `Form Model Binding` that you told me about?

Comment: Can't be sure without more information but it sounds like it could be your route declaration? have you created a post route?

Comment: in the update method, I guess, I need a `put` method not `post` right? so I declared a `put` request in my form like this: `{{Form::model($data, array(
'route' => array('waitingtimes.update', $data->id)
, 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer',
'method', => 'put'
))}}` have I forgotten somthing?

Comment: If your update method responds to a `put` request then you will need a `put`. You may also need to designate the route it is submitting the data to. `'route' => array('foo.bar', $data->id)`

Comment: I already have that design in my form. Okay no problem, I will check the problem myself, thanks